# How to Hide StatusBar between API 8 to API 19

Tags: java, android, xml

In my app I want to hide the statusbar. How do I do this between API 8 and API 19?

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Did you check the developer docs? http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// HIDE THE STATUS BAR
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

## To Remove TitleBar(Action bar)

use this in oncrete but before setcontentview(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

```
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

## To Remove status bar

use this in oncrete but before setcontentview(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT);

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: app unfortunately stopped when used this code: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: use this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: still app unfortunate stop after using `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`